# Hardware switch

Tags: wireless

I accidentally disabled my wifi network and now the combination of keys is not helping to enable it. It's 'hard blocked' but I don't know the button that would help me enable my wifi network.

Comment: Please put the output of `rfkill list` command to make sure the wifi is hard blocked. Try Fn+F1 (try from F1 to F12) until you find which compination enables your wifi. If there isn't any switch which enables and disables wifi (my laptop has one), then there will be a bios setting for enabling-disabling wifi.

Comment: First of all, open a terminal and run the command `rfkill list`. Then, copy the outcome and edit your question so that it includes it. BIOS is not something ubuntu has, but your computer. You can access it when you power up your pc usually with del or F2 or F8 (or some else key depending on your pc). If you want tell us your computer model and I will look it up.

Comment: It's del latitude 3450. Ya it's F2. But I got it back. I pressed fn+prntscreen when I just started my laptop. Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should still have the indicator in unity panel in the top right corner. Click it (usually arrow up down) and click enable wi-fi.

Comment: I think this works only if it is soft blocked. It won't work for hard blocked wifi.